# Crop image and download it with specific size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I modified a code to upload an image with specific size and I'm here right now:

```js
imageUploadPrepare();

function imageUploadPrepare() {

  var $profileImgDiv = document.getElementById("profile-img-div"),
      $profileImg = document.getElementById("profile-img"),
      $changePhoto = document.getElementById("change-photo"),
      $xPosition = document.getElementById("x-position"),
      $yPosition = document.getElementById("y-position"),
      $saveImg = document.getElementById("save-img"),
      $loader = document.getElementById("loader"),
      $cancelImg = document.getElementById("cancel-img"),
      $profileImgInput = document
        .getElementById("profile-img-input"),
      $profileImgConfirm = document
        .getElementById("profile-img-confirm"),
      $error = document.getElementById("error");

  var currentProfileImg = "",
      profileImgDivW = getSizes($profileImgDiv).elW,
      NewImgNatWidth = 0,
      NewImgNatHeight = 0,
      NewImgNatRatio = 0,
      NewImgWidth = 0,
      NewImgHeight = 0,
      NewImgRatio = 0,
      xCut = 0,
      yCut = 0;

  makeSquared($profileImgDiv);

  $changePhoto.addEventListener("change", function() {
    currentProfileImg = $profileImg.src;
    showPreview(this, $profileImg);
    $loader.style.width = "100%";
    $profileImgInput.style.display = "none";
    $profileImgConfirm.style.display = "flex";
    $error.style.display = "none";
  });

  $xPosition.addEventListener("input", function() {
    $profileImg.style.left = -this.value + "px";
    xCut = this.value;
    yCut = 0;
  });

  $yPosition.addEventListener("input", function() {
    $profileImg.style.top = -this.value + "px";
    yCut = this.value;
    xCut = 0;
  });

  $saveImg.addEventListener("click", function() {
    cropImg($profileImg);
    resetAll(true);
  });

  $cancelImg.addEventListener("click", function() {
    resetAll(false);
  });

  window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    makeSquared($profileImgDiv);
    profileImgDivW = getSizes($profileImgDiv).elW;
  });

  function makeSquared(el) {
    var elW = el.clientWidth;
    el.style.height = (elW * 0.82) + "px";
  }

  function showPreview(input, el) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          el.src = e.target.result;
        }, 300);

        var poll = setInterval(function() {
          if (el.naturalWidth && el.src != currentProfileImg) {
            clearInterval(poll);
            setNewImgSizes(el);
            setTimeout(function() {
              $loader.style.width = "0%";
              $profileImg.style.opacity = "1";
            }, 250);
          }
        }, 100);
      };
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }

  function setNewImgSizes(el) {
    if (getNatSizes(el).elR > 1) {
      el.style.width = "auto";
      el.style.height = "100%";
      newImgWidth = getSizes(el).elW;
      $xPosition.style.display = "block";
      $yPosition.style.display = "none";
      $xPosition.max = newImgWidth - profileImgDivW;
    } else if (getNatSizes(el).elR < 1) {
      el.style.width = "100%";
      el.style.height = "auto";
      newImgHeight = getSizes(el).elH;
      $xPosition.style.display = "none";
      $yPosition.style.display = "block";
      $yPosition.max = newImgHeight - profileImgDivW;
    } else if (getNatSizes(el).elR == 1) {
      el.style.width = "100%";
      el.style.height = "auto";
      $xPosition.style.display = "none";
      $yPosition.style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  function getNatSizes(el) {
    var elW = el.naturalWidth,
      elH = el.naturalHeight,
      elR = elW / elH;
    return {
      elW: elW,
      elH: elH,
      elR: elR
    };
  }

  function getSizes(el) {
    var elW = el.clientWidth,
      elH = el.clientHeight,
      elR = elW / elH;
    return {
      elW: elW,
      elH: elH,
      elR: elR
    };
  }

  function cropImg(el) {
    var natClientImgRatio = getNatSizes(el).elW / getSizes(el).elW;
    (myCanvas = document.getElementById("croppedPhoto")),
      (ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d"));
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 487);
    ctx.drawImage(
      el,
      xCut * natClientImgRatio,
      yCut * natClientImgRatio,
      profileImgDivW * natClientImgRatio,
      profileImgDivW * natClientImgRatio,
      0,
      0,
      400,
      487
    );
    var newProfileImgUrl = myCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    $profileImg.src = newProfileImgUrl;
    uploadImage(newProfileImgUrl);

    function uploadImage(image) {
      const dashboardProfileImage = document.getElementById('profile-img');
      dashboardProfileImage.src = image;

      downloadImage(image);

      dashboardProfileImage.download = "output.png";

      async function downloadImage(imageSrc) {
        const image = await fetch(imageSrc)
        const imageBlog = await image.blob()
        const imageURL = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlog)

        const link = document.createElement('a')
        link.href = imageURL
        link.download = 'image file name here'
        document.body.appendChild(link)
        link.click()
        document.body.removeChild(link)
      }



    }

    
  }

  function resetAll(confirm) {
    if (!confirm) {
      $profileImg.src = currentProfileImg;
    }
    $changePhoto.value = "";
    $profileImgInput.style.display = "block";
    $profileImgConfirm.style.display = "none";
    $profileImg.style.left = "0";
    $profileImg.style.top = "0";
    $profileImg.style.width = "100%";
    $profileImg.style.height = "100%";
    $xPosition.style.display = "none";
    $yPosition.style.display = "none";
    $xPosition.value = "0";
    $yPosition.value = "0";
    xCut = "0";
    yCut = "0";
  }

  function checkMinSizes(el) {
    if (getNatSizes(el).elW > 400 && getNatSizes(el).elH > 400) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/*Profile image*/

.profile-photo-div{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 40px auto;
  width: 320px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: ease .3s;
  -o-transition: ease .3s;
  transition: ease .3s;
}

.profile-photo-div .profile-img-div{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.profile-photo-div #loader{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #00cccf;
  z-index:10;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  -o-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}

.profile-photo-div #profile-img{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.profile-photo-div #change-photo{
  display: none;
}

.profile-photo-div .profile-buttons-div{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.profile-photo-div .button{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding:15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #8f7cff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.profile-photo-div .button:hover{
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.profile-photo-div .button:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .9s;
  -o-transition: .9s;
  transition: .9s;
}

.profile-photo-div .button:hover:after{
  -webkit-transform: scale(50);
  -ms-transform: scale(50);
  transform: scale(50);
  opacity: 1;
}

.profile-photo-div .button.half{
  width: 50%;
}

.profile-photo-div .green{
  background-color: #15ae6b;
}

.profile-photo-div .red{
  background-color: #ae0000;
}

.profile-photo-div #x-position{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: none;
}

.profile-photo-div #y-position{
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(90deg);
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(90deg);
  display: none;
}

.profile-photo-div canvas{
  position: absolute;
  top: -2000px;
  left: -2000px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.profile-photo-div .profile-img-confirm{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.profile-photo-div .error{
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: red;
  text-align:center;
  display: none;
}

/*end of profile image*/
```

```html
<div class="profile-photo-div" id="profile-photo-div">
                      <div class="profile-img-div" id="profile-img-div" style="height: 150px;">
                        <div id="loader"></div>
                        <img id="profile-img" src="/dashboard/img/default-user.png">
                        <input id="x-position" type="range" name="x-position" value="0" min="0">
                        <input id="y-position" type="range" name="y-position" value="0" min="0">
                      </div>
                      <div class="profile-buttons-div">
                        <div class="profile-img-input" id="profile-img-input">
                          <label class="button" id="change-photo-label" for="change-photo">UPLOAD PHOTO</label>
                          <input id="change-photo" name="change-photo" type="file" style="display: none;" accept="image/*">
                        </div>
                        <div class="profile-img-confirm" id="profile-img-confirm" style="display: none;">
                          <div class="button half green" id="save-img">
                            <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                          </div>
                          <div class="button half red" id="cancel-img">
                            <i class="fa fa-remove" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="error" id="error">حداقل سایز مجاز 400&#215;400</div>
                      <canvas id="croppedPhoto" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
                    </div>
```

The issue is so far the image is always cropped with fixed dimensions of **400 * 400** pixels !!

But **I want to crop them at 454.138px * 306px** and no matter how I modify the numbers I always get that 400* 400 fix size?!

How can  fix this?

**NOTE:** Since Stack overflow snippet code is completely useless in order to test the code please use this Codepen:

https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/RwZGKBQ

Comment: Which numbers have you modified - your pen has 400x400 canvas dimensions in the HTML.

Comment: Change those ... you'll see nothing happens..

Comment: I changed them to 40 x 40 and the cropping was done correctly, a small square only was created as required. I used SO's snippet system to trial this.

Comment: Oh right I misunderstood you... then I get disproportion image preview : I changed the canvas to `<canvas id="croppedPhoto" width="455" height="306"></canvas>`